# SQL query HAVING SUM between two values

Tags: mysql, sql

At the moment I have a query looking for Sums lower the 2

```
 `HAVING SUM(`Place` < 2)`
```

Is it possible to have it between two values 1.5 and 2

```
 `HAVING SUM(`Place` between 2 and 1.5)`
```

My whole query would look as follows:

```
SELECT `tile`, `Date`, SUM(`Place` < 2) as sumtotal
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`, `Date`
HAVING SUM(`Place` between 2 and 1.5)  > 1 ;
```

Comment: The answer is yes

Comment: @GurV The answer is: "It depends on exact DBMS you're using"

Comment: Please add your DBMS in tag list

Comment: @Andy - I think that's MySQL in which case it *is* yes. Most databases won't even allow this kind of expressions

Comment: Standard SQL: `having sum(case place between 1.5 and 2 end) > 1`

Comment: yes its mysql but my output gives me no result

Comment: You have between on wrong order...should be  `between 1.5 and 2`. (Only `between symmetric` can have items in wrong order.)

Comment: @jarlh symmetric?

Comment: @Strawberry, yes. Doesn't MySQL support that?

Comment: @jarlh - perfect that worked. I thought it was the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You can use between in having

```
SELECT `tile`, `Date`, SUM(`Place` < 2) as sumtotal
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`, `Date`
HAVING  SUM(`Place` ) between 1.5 and 2 ;
```

Comment: I need there to be more than 1 results in the group hence the > 1

Answer (score 0):

Change the table_key for you table ID:

```
select `tile`, `Date`, SUM(`Place` < 2) as sumtotal
where table_key in (
(   SELECT table_key
        FROM TFResults
        GROUP BY `tile`, `Date`
        HAVING SUM(`Place` < 2)  > 1 )
AND
(   SELECT table_key 
        FROM TFResults
        GROUP BY `tile`, `Date`
        HAVING SUM(`Place` > 1.5)  > 1 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT `tile`, `Date`, SUM(`Place` < 2) as sumtotal
FROM TFResults
GROUP BY `tile`, `Date`
HAVING SUM((`Place` <= 2) AND (`Place` =>  1.5))  > 0 ;
```